# Flow formula returning null - but working in a formula field

Tags: visual-workflow, formula-field

I have a formula resource in my flow that calculates a currency amount from opportunity fields.  When the flow runs, the field that it is supposed to populate is blank and in debug it shows that the formula is returning "null.

However, when  I test the exact same formula in a formula field it returns the correct value. Is there something I am missing in my flow formula that could be causing it to return null?

`({!$Record.Currency1__c} - {!$Record.Currency2__c})+ {!$Record.Currency3__c} +{!$Record.Currency4__c} + {!$Record.Currency5__c} + {!$Record.Currency6__c} + {!$Record.Currency7__c} + {!$Record.Currency8__c} + {!$Record.Currency9__c} + {!$Record.Currency10__c} - {!$Record.Currency11__c} - {!$Record.Currency12__c}`

Genericized field names for confidentiality.
TIA

Comment: Are any of the individual fields null?

Comment: surround each operand with `BLANKVALUE(operand,0)`